# Setting a hook on the Socket API with plthook

Tags: linux, sockets, hook

I want to set a hook on the connect function, I tried to use the plthook for libc.so.6 but it only works if I made the process only hook, which means other .so modules in the process will use the original connect function

this code doesn't work the function connect wasn't found in PLT of the libc.so.6:

```
    plthook_t* plthook;
    if (plthook_open(&plthook, "libc.so.6") == 0)
    {
        if (plthook_replace(plthook, "connect", (void*)MyConnect, (void**)&orignConnect)) == 0)
        {
            //some error handling
        }
    }
```

if I change to this:

```
   plthook_t* plthook;
    if (plthook_open(&plthook, NULL) == 0)
    {
          if (plthook_replace(plthook, "connect", (void*)MyConnect, (void**)&orignConnect)) == 0)
        {
            //some error handling
        }
    }
```

this works, but only if the connect function is called from the process code, in other .so modules the original function is called. I wonder if the problem in that the connect function according to readelf is STB_LOCAL:

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 3019 entries:

```
|Num:|    Value          |Size |Type    |Bind   |Vis       |Ndx |Name
456: | 000000000014f600  | 155 |FUNC    |WEAK   |DEFAULT   |14  |connect@@GLIBC_2.2.5
3648:| 000000000014f600  | 155 |FUNC    |LOCAL  |DEFAULT   |14  |__libc_connect
7556:| 000000000014f600  | 155 |FUNC    |WEAK   |DEFAULT   |14  |connect
7570:| 000000000014f600  | 155 |FUNC    |WEAK   |DEFAULT   |14  |__connect
```

and according to the ELF documentation:

> STB_LOCAL Local symbols are not visible outside the object file
> containing their definition.     Local symbols of the same name may
> exist in multiple files without interfering with each    other.